# Convert JSON into array dataType

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON string

```
var json = {"result":[{"address":" Ardenham Court, Oxford Road ,AYLESBURY, BUCKINGHAMSHIRE ,UNITED KINGDOM","picture":"1.jpg","uniqueid":"8b54275a60088547d473d462763b4738","story":"I love my home. I feel safe, I am comfortable and I am loved. A home can't be a home without our parents and our loved ones. But sad to say, some are experiencing that eventhough their loved ones are in their houses, they are not loving each other. There is a big war. You can't call it a home."}]}
```

I want to get address ,picture,story  separately 
for accomplish  this.  I tried recent answers in stackoverflow, but I was not able to achieve it.

Below is what I have tried,

```
$.each(json.result.address, function (index, value) {

        // Get the items
        var items = this.address; // Here 'this' points to a 'group' in 'groups'

        // Iterate through items.
        $.each(items, function () {
            console.log(this.text); // Here 'this' points to an 'item' in 'items'
        });
    });
```

Comment: json.result[0].address

Comment: Why do you want to do that? json object can be used an arrray.

Comment: i want to get field separately and display it on table

Comment: The json looks quite badly structured though, if you want to get the lines of the address you'll have to split the address value string by a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(json.result, function (index, value) {
    console.log(this.address); // this will give you all addresses
    console.log(this.picture); //this will give you all pictures
    console.log(this.uniqueid); //this will give you all unique id's
    console.log(this.story); //this will give you all stories
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Lf51kkye/)**

Answer (score 0):

If u want it in array then u can use split function like below

```
var address=json.result[0].address.split(",");
var picture=json.result[0].picture.split(",");
var story =json.result[0].story.split(",");
```

if there are more the 1 result in json then

```
    var address=[];
    var picture=[];
    var story =[];
  for (var i=0;i<json.result.length;i++){
  address=address.concat(json.result[i].address.split(","));
  picture=picture.concat(json.result[i].picture.split(","));
  story =story .concat(json.result[i].story.split(","));
}
```

Comment: i have  multiple address  [],[] like how can loop this

Comment: then traverse each result & concat

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
for(x in json.result){
    alert(json.result[x].address);
    alert(json.result[x].picture);
    alert(json.result[x].uniqueid);
    alert(json.result[x].story);
}
```